# Google Play: if a user already has a subscription, can promo-code applying to delay the next payment date?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

Is there any other way to gift a PRO user with a free subs day? The motivation here: we want to make a "gift for continuous subs" - if a user is a PRO user for 3 months in a row, he receives an extra month for free (or something like that). Now we need to find technical ways to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it turns out it is possible: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#defer

Comment: Have you integrated that into your app? They said it is possible on the page you linked, but while trying to redeem a promotional code for an active subscription gplay displays an error that subscription is already activated..

Comment: @Beloo No, in the end we didn't implement this functionality.

Comment: @Beloo It seems that this is not exactly related to promo codes, this API just defers the next payment to the specified date.